# Best way to have manageable embedded XSD / XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'd appreciate some guidance on which way to start looking. I feel there must be a proper solution for this but it's out of my reach.

So given application 1: AppA with schema: XsdA
I don't have any control over these but I have to work with XsdA and among other things output xml that comforms to XsdA.

Application 2: AppB is what I'm working on. This has it's own schema XsdB that I have full control over.

What I'd like to do is somehow XsdB is an extension or an extended version of XdsA. A few extra elements here a few other attributes there. Stuff that is already in XsdA would not change.

Obviously I could just copy XsdA and add my mods to it, but I'm wondering how could I do this in a structured, trackable way. Let's say AppA release a new version with a new XsdA, how do I propagate those changes to my XsdB other than diffing?

I'm hoping that this is part of some random but common workflow somewhere so there are tool and methods to overcome this automatically.

All ideas are highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on whether XsdA has been designed with extensibility in mind. Does it have types that allow wildcard elements in external namespaces, for example?

If it hasn't been designed for extensibility, then you have all the problems you describe. One approach to the maintainability of your extensions is that rather than forking the definitions/declarations in XsdA, you maintain an XSLT transformation that constructs XsdB from XsdA.

Comment: I was trying really hard to convince the owning group to pepper the original with a bunch of any elements but they didn't like the idea.
XSLT looks really promising though. I have to dig into it but it seems this can do everything I need. Thanks Michael!